# Gmail Drive vs Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I know about **Google Drive** service, which is a file storage and synchronization service created by Google. It allows users to store files in the cloud.

I recently found [Gmail Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMail_Drive) at Wikipedia.

I don't understand the difference.

Can anybody explain in simple words?

Comment: Consider to improve and/or discuss the referred article through  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:GMail_Drive. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Talk_page_guidelines to learn about the Wikipedia talk pages.

Answer (score 3):

Before Google Drive existed, someone came up with the idea to use Gmail to store files. At the time, Gmail offered more storage than any of the nascent cloud storage solutions. (The free offerings, at least.)

From what I recall, it worked by attaching files to special messages in your "Drafts" folder and there was a Web interface that let you work with them as if it was a simple file store.

It was not a service offered by Google; it was created by a third party.